# Merging variable with string in config file

Tags: nginx, configuration

I the have following setup in my conf file

```
upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
```

But I want change chosen param name to:

```
upload_set_form_field ($upload_field_name+"[name]") "$upload_file_name";
```

So I can get "attachment[name]" but this doesn't work. I would be very happy if someone could help me with merging variables with string in nginx config file :).

Answer (score 67):

This works:

```
set $foo = 'foo';
set $foobar "${foo}bar";
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks. I did this: `set $object "$1"; set $object "${object}Display";`

Answer (score 6):

Nginx does not have a concatenation character, rather it's based on valid and invalid characters, for instance in the directive:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
```

$uri is the variable and / is a string to append since / cannot be in a variable name.

Similarly you should try

```
$upload_field_name[name] "$upload_file_name";
```

If this doesn't work then try.

```
set $foo [name];
$upload_field_name$foo "$upload_file_name";
```

I cannot say if the upload module will even allow this, though.
Minor syntax errors might also be present.